# Vue3 app does not built as descriped in docs

Tags: vue.js, npm, build, vuejs3

I have simple [vue3](/questions/tagged/vue3) app. **It run well with `npm run dev`** but when I try, *as described in the [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#with-build-tools)*, `npm run build` to ship it to production, I got the error below:

```
$ npm run build

> salaty@0.0.0 build
> vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build

src/main.ts:2:17 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './Salaty.vue'. '/home/path/to/Salaty/src/Salaty.vue.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

2 import App from './Salaty.vue'
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

This `src/main.ts` :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './Salaty.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

The application run well in dev. I don't know what is the problem?! I don't think I have to rename files manually before build, do it?!

#### Update:

`Salaty.vue` src:

```
<script>
/*let baseUrl = 'https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json';
let city = 'kafr-saqr';
let timeformat = 1;
let school = 5;*/
import config from './config.json';
import moment from 'moment'
import LoadingComp from './components/LoadingComp.vue';
import Clock from './components/Clock.vue'
export default{
    data(){
        return {
            dataRes: null,
            times: null,
            now: moment(),
            nextTime: null,
            error: null,
            day: 'today.json'
        }
    },
    computed: {
        fetchUrl(){
            console.log(config.baseUrl+this.day+'?city='+config.city+'&timeformat='+config.timeformat+'&school='+config.school)
            return config.baseUrl+this.day+'?city='+config.city+'&timeformat='+config.timeformat+'&school='+config.school;
        },
        
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchData(){            
            this.dataRes = null;
            try{
                const res = await fetch(this.fetchUrl);
                this.dataRes = await res.json();                
            }
            catch(error){
                this.error= 'Error! Could not reach the API.\n' + error;
                alert(this.error)
            }
        },        
    },
    mounted(){
        this.fetchData();
        localStorage.setItem("city",config.city);
    },
    components:{
        LoadingComp,Clock
    },
    watch:{
        dataRes(){
            if (!this.dataRes) return null;
            const cTimes = config.filteredTimes.reduce((obj, key)=>({ ...obj, [key]: this.dataRes.results.datetime[0].times[key] }),{});
            
            for (const t in cTimes){
                cTimes[t]=moment(this.dataRes.results.datetime[0].date.gregorian+' '+cTimes[t]);
                //console.log(cTimes[t].unix(), this.nextTime, t, typeof(this.nextTime))
                if (cTimes[t].unix() > this.now.unix() && this.nextTime == null){
                    this.nextTime = cTimes[t];
                   // console.log("YYYYY> ", cTimes[t],t)
                     cTimes[t].next = true;
                }
            }
            if (this.nextTime == null){
                this.day = 'tomorrow.json';
            }
            this.times = cTimes;            
        },
        day(){
            this.fetchData();
        },
        /*nextTime(){
            this.nextTime == null
            this.fetchData();
        }*/
    },

};
</script>
<template>
<Clock @response="(p) => {if(p > this.nextTime) this.fetchData()}" :nextTime="this.nextTime" />
{{ dataRes? dataRes.results.location.city:''}}
<ul v-if="times">
    <li v-for="(time,k,i) in times">{{k}} > {{time.format('hh:mm a')}} <strong v-if="time.next">* Upcoming</strong></li>
</ul>
{{times? times.Fajr:''}}
    <div v-if="!dataRes && error == null"><LoadingComp /></div>
    <pre v-if="dataRes">{{dataRes}}</pre>
  
</template>
```

Comment: What is the content of `Salaty.vue` ?

Comment: @MichalLevý checkout the update.

Comment: If you open your project in VS Code, do you get any errors from Volar? The thing is that in dev mode (`npm run dev`) Vite does not run TS in "check for type errors" mode - [source](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#overview) but is does in prod build mode. So you probably have a TS error in your code....

Comment: In Vue 3 components should be defined using `export default defineComponent({})` instead of just `export default {}` - https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#definecomponent

Comment: And your script tag should be `<script lang="ts">`

Comment: Well if you are actually using TS of course :) If not, I do not know why Vite is running `vue-tsc` before build

Comment: I don't use type script as shown in the updated code snippet. I would like to **confirm** that it works fine in dev. Additionally, the code could be described as a little modification  of [the 15 steps official get started tutorial](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-1)

Comment: How did you actually created the project? It seems you have `vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build` in `package.config` as a build command, which is really strange for project not using TS. Also you explicitly mentioned `main.ts` in your question so I'm really perplexed

Comment: @MichalLevý using `npm init vue@latest` However, in the installation dialog I chose no to typescript. [As shown here](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#local)

Comment: @SaidbakR Given that you have a file named `src/main.ts` (the `.ts` file extension is for TypeScript files), and your build command includes `vue-tsc`, I'm guessing you might've chosen *Yes* at the TypeScript prompt (when you meant *No*). You could re-scaffold your project, or manually remove TypeScript from your project (i.e., rename `src/main.ts` to `src/main.js`, remove `vue-tsc` from the build command, and remove TypeScript related dependencies).

Comment: @tony19 You are right. Unfortunately the init wizard is unclear, what you are supposed  no, it gives yes. I think it is styling issue in the shell script.